# I want to copy a range to clipboard with criteria

Tags: excel, vba, copy, row

I want copy a range with the following criteria

1 - Copy the entire row, including hidden columns

2 - If the Colunm "CC" has no value, them it will skip the entire row

Note Update = Sorry I forgot something, it won't always be two rows that will have data, sometimes they will have data in 3 4 5.... or in all the rows of the table

Note = My table has formulas so I don't want to mess with them, just copy the cell values

Im using this

```
Sub CopyVisible()
  Worksheets(1).Range("B3:I13").Select
    Selection.Copy
    
End Sub
```

And im getting this result

[image]

But i want this result

[image]

Im gonna copy to clipboard, then i will paste on another worksheet mannualy

With Xavier Junqué's code I'm having this result, the only problem is that he is selecting one more line

Code:

```
Sub CopyFilledCells()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("B3:I3")
    Worksheets(1).Activate
    For i = 3 To Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If Worksheets(1).Range("B" & i).Value = "" Then Exit For
    Next
    Range(rng, rng.Offset(i - 3, 0)).Select
    Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change instruction

```
Worksheets(1).Range("B3:I13").Select
```

to

```
Worksheets(1).Range("B3:I4").Select
```

Then, only two rows (rows# 3 and 4)  between columns B and I will be copied. When pasting excel shows pasting options: select option copy only values.

Perhaps try the following:

```
Sub CopyFilledCells()
    Worksheets(1).Activate
    Worksheets(1).Range(Range("B3:I3"), Range("B3").End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

Another try:

```
Sub CopyFilledCells()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("B3:I3")
    Worksheets(1).Activate
    For i = 3 To Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If Worksheets(1).Range("B" & i).Value = "" Then Exit For
    Next
    Range(rng, rng.Offset(i - 3, 0)).Select
    Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot something, it won't always be two rows that will have data, sometimes they will have data in 3 4 5.... or in all the rows of the table

Comment: Then, the code should know beforehand how many rows to copy and, in that case, employ Worksheets(1).Range("B3:I" + (howmanyrows+3) ).Select where howmanyrows is the variable with the number of rows to copy.

Comment: Please, take a look to the code I just added and take a try.

Comment: It's copying the entire table, it's not skipping the lines like I want, is it because of the formulas I have in the CC column?

Comment: @Cooper Copies the entire table because there is an occupied cell at the bottom of the table. But, please, make a try with the last code I have posted. Thanks.

Comment: Almost, gonna update with the result

Answer (score 1):

i think the following code will do the job.

```
Sub CopyFilledCells()
  Dim lngLastRow As Long

  Sheet2.UsedRange.Clear
  With Sheet1
   lngLastRow = .Range("I2").End(xlDown).Row
   .Range("B3:I" & lngLastRow).Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A1")
  End With

End Sub
```

Regards
Bernd

Comment: Im getting error on " Sheet2.UsedRange.Clear"

Comment: you don't have a sheet named Sheet2?

Comment: the name of the worksheet is "GERAL", I replaced it but it's still giving error "THE OBJECT IS MANDATORY"

Comment: take the name of sheet, which is left in the project-explorer. I think you take the name in Brackets?